# Munin like tool to create graphs on the fly in PHP

Tags: php, graph, rrd, munin

Do you know any good library which doesnt require an external module like RRD and can create munin like graphs on the fly, using a database backend?

Comment: is this of any use? http://jpgraph.net/

Comment: Nah, I don't need fancy .... need something like this: http://php-rrd-grapher.sourceforge.net/example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

It does require GD2 though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Open Flash Chart: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/, but as the name implies it uses flash (not sure if that's an issue for you).